# Javascript onclick div element load page similar to link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, onclick

How do I load another page on the onClick event in Javascript?

```
<div id="div_man" onclick="/subfolder/index.htm"></div>
```

The code above is not working.
Please explain. I am sure it's quite simple. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<div id="div_man" onclick="location.href='/subfolder/index.htm'"></div>
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/EEjyP/

Comment: The `javascript:` part is not needed.The browser knows that the content of onclick and other onevent attributes is JavaScript.